# ASP.NET application behaves differently between production servers

Tags: asp.net, debugging

Our asp.net app is running on 10 web servers, after we deployed the new release today, we noticed that some servers work, some do not.

The one not working has no exception, it just behaves the old way, it looks like still runing on old assemblies.

I have checked the assembly in bin folder between good and bad servers, the size, timestamp are all same, the code are same as well in reflector.

What else can I do? can you help to shed some lights?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be absolute that the updates will reflected sure Use this procedure when you make the update.

- Open/Create the **app_offline.htm** file
  on the root.
- Update/copy the new files and binaries. Even if you just add an empty line on web.config your site will be restarted and updated
- Delete/Rename the **app_offline.htm** file

You can do even now, open the app_offline.htm, add an empty line on web.config and saved so system note that at least one update have been done, close the app_offline.htm and your sites will be update with the minimum cost.

Comment: app_offline.htm is not required to reset IIS/the website.  Its purely a tool to facilitate a smooth update cycle (by preventing errors during the update).  That said, The OP did update his site and confirmed that the files copied correctly, but the site did not update.  The next step is to kill the worker processes/iisreset.

Comment: @Kyle How to run run the iisreset ? it is possible if you do not have access to the server console ? And if you are on a multi web site server, the iisreset reset one site only, or all ?

Comment: You would run it via the command console on the server.  The method you describe above works, but in cases like the OP is experiencing where the files have been updated and IIS didn't pick up the changes, IIS would need to be reset on the server, and the command would need to be run on each server.  Your answer isn't wrong, I'm just adding a note that IIS might need to reset manually in cases like this.

Comment: @kyle you see, you need console. Try the one I say, open the app_offline, make a small change on web.config, save it, close the app_offline and there you are, the updates will be done. Check it out. The open of the app_offline.htm is force the site to make restart.

Comment: just follow up, copying whole bin folder from good server to bad server solved the problem. still do not what was the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the command `iisreset` on those servers that are affected.  This should force IIS to reload the assemblies into memory.

Comment: IT ops confirmed that they did IISREST on each server after code release.

Answer (score 0):

IIS/.net cache a the application in `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files` (depending on the version of .net you are running, of course).  You may want to delete the cached version of your application and reset iis (`iisreset.exe`) to see if that clears up your problem.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2008/08/11/clearing-out-temporary-asp-net-files.aspx) is a handy post on the subject.